rror: Cannot find native module 'ExpoLocalization', js engine: hermes in Expo React Native app
I am trying to implement localization for Expo React Native app.
My i18n.js file looks like this:
import { getLocales } from 'expo-localization';
import { I18n } from 'i18n-js';

// Set the key-value pairs for the different languages you want to support.
const i18n = new I18n({
  en: { welcome: 'Hello' },
  lt: { welcome: 'Labas' },
});

// Set the locale once at the beginning of your app.
i18n.locale = getLocales()[0].languageCode;

console.log(i18n.t('welcome'));

I did
npm install expo-localization
npx expo install i18n-js

And I launch with
npx expo start

I get error:
Cannot find native module 'ExpoLocalization', js engine: hermes

My versions in package-lock.json:
    "i18n-js": "^4.4.3",

    "expo-localization": "~15.0.3",

I also tried setting jsEngine in app.json:
  "expo": {
    "jsEngine": "hermes",

None of this really helped. Any suggestions?

Did you tried setting up the plugin config in app.json || app.config.json? I wonder it's a issue related to native codes not existing, please add the expo-localization in your plugin array, and run prebuild command i.e. npx expo prebuild or eas-build npx expo run:android

I tried this but it didn't help. Same error cannot find native module 'ExpoLocalization'

I wonder, if you tried to recompile the app or not? did you tried to use eas build command? eas build --profile development --platform android

Yes, I have tried just now and same result - Cannot find native module 'ExpoLocalization', js engine: hermes

Did you eject the app?

Yes, it didn't help. I did  expo eject     and then run my project with npx expo start

Something was wrong with my project. I also needed maps but it didnt allowed me to use maps either. So I created new project using
npx create-expo-app react-native-maps-demo
cd react-native-maps-demo

And then it worked - I was able to add localization as well as maps.

The error mentions "ExpoLocalization", but the correct package name is expo-localization. There's clearly a difference, and this could be causing the issue. We need more details on the error to be sure.
In the meantime, check your app.json to make sure it includes the plugin:
 {
  "expo": {
    "plugins": ["expo-localization"]
  }
}

Try deleting node_modules and package-lock.json may be you used npm and yarn.
Update :
This how i use getLocales :
import { getLocales } from "expo-localization";  
import { I18n } from "i18n-js";  
  
import translations from "../app/locales/translations.json";  
const i18n = new I18n(translations);  
export const locale = getLocales()[0].languageCode || "en";  
i18n.locale = locale;  
export { i18n };.

Try this and give me feedback.

Yes, I have this in my app.json file:
"plugins": [
"expo-router",
"expo-localization"
],
I understand package is expo-localization not ExpoLocalization but this error happens exactly when I try to import { getLocales } from 'expo-localization';

Please check my anwser update

I have tried to delete node_modules it didn't help unfortunately. Also its not about locales its that first lnie which already gives error import { getLocales } from "expo-localization";  I can change it to import "expo-localization";  and it still gives error
